How do people post comments with accounts that disappear almost immediately thereafter?
IIRC one needs some level of rep (looks like 50) to post comments. Yet I've seen greyed out accounts (non-clickable user links) post several comments in a row, from different user numbers. How does this work? Do they associate then quickly disassociate their SE accounts with P.SE, to use association bonus (just) to post comments?

Can you provide an example?

@F1Krazy here https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/89337/18373

Well, while it might be a tad annoying, StackOverflow has an outsized phenomenon of 1 Rep users posting one question and then never coming back, accepting, interacting with clarifications, etc...  I now have a mental filter of not bothering to answer questions from users with less than 50-60 rep from other questions, because it is such a thankless activity.  Quite possible a lot of this homework/assignment driven by people who don't want to leave traces, but  I am surprised old-timers seem to still fall for that and spend time answering.

Unfortunately, it's a 'feature' of the association bonus in that users active elsewhere on the network can create an account on a site, comment, and then delete their newly created account, leaving comments intact. This is especially a problem when the commenting privilege is abused, as there is no account left for mods to contact/suspend. However, we can investigate to see if there is a history of this behaviour by a user if such comments are brought to our attention, and if appropriate, we can get in touch with CMs for cross-network action.
I've cleaned up the comments from your example because they were dissolving into name-calling.
